# Laravel 5.4 not recognizing correct php version

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, php-7.1

I just moved a website that uses Laravel 5.4 from one host to another. Im getting an error that it cannot connect to the db but in the logs I see:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in /var/www/staging/data/www/website.com/vendor/spatie/laravel-activitylog/src/helpers.php on line 6
```

I looked this up and it is clear that the error is produced if you have the wrong version of php, spatie requires 7^. I do a php -v and it says I have php 5.6 but I run phpinfo() and it says php 7.1. I have multiple versions of php on my server. How do I get this Laravel install to recognize the correct one? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you remove the old versions? If yes, remove it and run composer update

Comment: So, are you want to change php version from 7 to 5.6?

Comment: I wasn't able to remove the old version. It seems like its only not working now on the command line. If I run it like /opt/php71/bin/php artisan config:clear it works fine but php artisan config:clear breaks. Its because of the plugin, not the actual laravel install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP version depends on how the web server is set up. It looks like a type hint error so you definitely need at least 7.0 for the code to run. You can try researching your hosting provider and see if there is a way to set the PHP version used by the Apache or Nginx web server.

Answer (score 0):

please check the php version of your hosting server and php 7.0 also work for laravel 5.4 because i also use that in my project it does'nt make any issue.

hope you check your server php version which is less than laravel 5.4 required.

Thank You